# Why can't we apply value iteration when we do not know the reward and transition functions, and how does Q-learning solve this issue?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, markov-decision-process, value-iteration

I don't understand why we can't apply *value iteration* when don't know the reward and transition probabilities. In [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifma8G7LegE&feature=youtu.be&t=3431&ab_channel=CS188Spring2013), the lecturer says it has to do with not being able to take max with samples, but what does this mean?

Why does Q-learning not need to know the reward and transition functions? In Q-learning, we also have a max, so I am not understanding.

Answer (score 3):

For normal [value iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process#Value_iteration), you need to have the model, i.e. the transition probability, denoted by $P(s' \mid s,a)$.

With Q-learning, you use the current reward and the already stored Q value:

[image: Q value update]

The relation between the value function $V(s)$ and the $Q$ function $Q(s, a)$ is that the $V(s)$ function is simply the value of the action $a$, such that $Q(s, a)$ is the highest, that is, $V(s) = \max_a Q(s, a)$.